# Does the assignment in Saving Private Ryan come impossibly fast?

Tags: saving-private-ryan

On D-day, the body of Ryan's brother is shown on the beach.  That death is reported to Washington, noticed by typists, taken to the brass, who decides on the rescue mission, which is assigned (on D-day+3?) to Captain Miller while his company is still in place near the established beachhead.  Did Ranger companies really linger near the beach for that long, and didn't the red tape of casualty reports take substantial time to process, so the depicted turnaround is faster than what would ever have possibly occurred?

Comment: Well, the amount of time, money and man power devoted to D-Day would dictate that troop movement and causality details get top priority.

Comment: [This link](http://fivethirtyeight.com/features/the-challenge-of-counting-d-days-dead/) says "In most cases, [casualty reports] were not filed until the 8th, and most of those were handwritten and typed later in June".  I haven't found if Ranger companies stayed at the beachhead for days or immediately continued fighting farther inland, but my guess is logistics would have made the 3-day turnaround, and with Rangers still on the beachhead, highly unlikely.